# Ruby Block Syntax Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-error, block, carrierwave

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ruby block and unparenthesized arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420147/ruby-block-and-unparenthesized-arguments)

I'm not sure I understand this syntax error. I'm using Carrierwave to manage some file uploads in a Rails app, and I seem to be passing a block to one of the methods incorrectly.

Here's the example in the [Carrierwave Docs](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave):

```
version :thumb do
  process :resize_to_fill => [200,200]
end
```

Here's what I had:

```
version :full   { process(:resize_to_limit => [960, 960]) }
version :half   { process(:resize_to_limit => [470, 470]) }
version :third  { process(:resize_to_limit => [306, 306]) }
version :fourth { process(:resize_to_limit => [176, 176]) }
```

The above doesn't work, I get `syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end`. Interestingly enough, the following works perfectly:

```
version :full   do process :resize_to_limit => [960, 960]; end
version :half   do process :resize_to_limit => [470, 470]; end
version :third  do process :resize_to_limit => [306, 306]; end
version :fourth do process :resize_to_limit => [176, 176]; end
```

So, my question is, why can I pass a block using `do...end` but not braces in this instance?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Code block passed to `each` works with brackets but not with `do`-`end` (ruby)](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6718340/), [Block definition - difference between braces and `do`-`end` ?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6179442/), [Ruby multiline block without `do` `end`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3680097/), [Using `do` block vs brackets `{}`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2122380/), [What is the difference or value of these block coding styles in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/533008/) and [Ruby block and unparenthesized arguments](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/420147/).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
version(:full)   { process(:resize_to_limit => [960, 960]) }
version(:half)   { process(:resize_to_limit => [470, 470]) }
version(:third)  { process(:resize_to_limit => [306, 306]) }
version(:fourth) { process(:resize_to_limit => [176, 176]) }
```

You have a precedence problem. The `{ }` block binds tighter than a `do...end` block and tighter than a method call; the result is that Ruby thinks you're trying to supply a block as an argument to a symbol and says no.

You can see a clearer (?) or possibly more familar example by comparing the following:

```
[1, 2, 3].inject 0  { |x, y| x + y }
[1, 2, 3].inject(0) { |x, y| x + y }
```