# Couldn't understand the difference between `puts{}.class` and `puts({}.class)`

Tags: ruby

As the anonymous block and hash block looks like approximately same. I was doing kind of playing with it. And doing do I reached to some serious observations as below:

```
{}.class
#=> Hash
```

Okay,It's cool. empty block is considered as `Hash`.

```
print{}.class
#=> NilClass
puts {}.class

#=> NilClass
```

Now why the above code showing the same as `NilClass`,but the below code shows the `Hash` again ?

```
puts ({}.class)
#Hash
#=> nil
print({}.class)
#Hash=> nil
```

Could anyone help me here to understand that what's going one above?

I completely disagree with the point of **@Lindydancer**

How would you explain the below lines:

```
print {}.class
#NilClass
print [].class
#Array=> nil
print (1..2).class
#Range=> nil
```

Why not the same with the below `print [].class` and `print (1..2).class`?

***EDIT***

When ambiguity happens with `local variable` and `method` call, Ruby throws an error about the fact as below :

```
name
#NameError: undefined local variable or method `name' for main:Object
#        from (irb):1
#        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Now not the same happens with `{}` (as there is also an ambiguity between `empty code block` or `Hash` block). As IRB also here not sure if it's a `empty block` or `Hash`. Then why the error didn't throw up when IRB encountered `print {}.class` or `{}.class`?

Comment: About the "ambiguity": IRB does not throw an error because it is ambiguous, it throws an error because it can *neither* find a local variable, *nor* a method with the name `name`.

Comment: @Lindydancer I mentioned that fact, but wanted to know why not the same with `{}` ambiguity? :)

Comment: @Mischa This is an ambiguity when we place say `name` to the IRB, if it's a method or local variable, when the variable is not created via an assignment operation or a method is with the same defined there.Due to the ambiguity Ruby throws an error. *This is the fact*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby block and unparenthesized arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420147/ruby-block-and-unparenthesized-arguments)

Comment: @theTinMan No way it is duplicated. This is totally different from the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{}` in this case is recognized as block passed to `print`, while `[]` unambiguously means empty array.

```
print {}.class                            # => NilClass
print do;end.class                        # => NilClass
```

Comment: Yeah! may be you are right. But it is never for `precedence` as **Lindydancer** said. That is wrong. I proved that.

Comment: **FYI** `do;end.class` and `{}.class` is not same when you typed it in `IRB` only without any printing statement.

Comment: @iAmRubuuu yes, block makes no sense without method call, so `{}` by itself (not after method call) can not mean anything other then empty hash.

Answer (score 6):

The precedence rules of ruby makes `print{}.class` interpreted as `(print{}).class`. As `print` apparently returns a `nil` the `class` method returns `#NilClass`.

*EDIT*: As been discussed on other answers and in the updates to the question, `print{}` it *of course* interpreted as calling `print` with a block, not a hash. However, this is still about precedence as `{}` binds stronger than `[]` and `(1..2)` (and stronger than `do ... end` for that matter).

Comment: It is the right explanation. Order of precedence determines what part of the operation occurs first. We see this question multiple times a week. You can fix the problem with the appropriate use of parenthesis to control precedence.

Comment: @theTinMan explanation is still incorrect. Did you try anything or only read the answer and mapped with the link and said here he is right. Just give a try `(print() {}).class`. And think `(print{}).class` and `(print() {}).class` same or not ? because `print {}.class` is parsed as `(print() {}).class` where `{}` is the closure block and not a Hash.

Comment: Don't be rude and insulting. I read your question, and the answer. This remains an order of precedence issue as I see it.

Answer (score 1):

You are running into some nuances of Ruby, where characters mean different things depending on context. How the source code is interpreted follows rules, one of which is that `{}` is a closure block *if it follows a method call*, and otherwise a Hash constructor.

It's common throughout the language to see characters mean different things depending on context or position within the statement.

---

#### Examples:

Parens `()` used for method call or for precedence

```
print(1..5).class => NilClass
print (1..5).class => Range <returns nil>
```

Square brackets `[]` used to call `:[]` method or for Array

```
print[].class => NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
print([].class) => Array <returns nil>
```

Asterisk `*` used for multiplication or splatting

```
1 * 5 => 5
[*1..5] => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Ampersand `&` used for symbol -> proc or logical and

```
0 & 1 => 0
[1, 2, 3].map(&:to_s) => ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Or in your case, braces used for block closures or for a hash

```
... hope it makes sense now ...
```

Comment: `Asterisk * used for multiplication or splatting`, don't forget using it to repeat an array `[1] * 2 => [1, 1]` and repeating strings `"1" * 2 => "11"`. `&` is also a set-operation: `[1,2] & [2]
=> [2]` as are `+` and `|`. And the "ambiguity" isn't limited to Ruby as Perl has the same issues.

Comment: haha @theTinMan not meant to be exhaustive. I also consider the other uses of asterisk as a sort of metaphorical multiplication, likewise with union and intersection on arrays

Comment: interesting about Perl- never done much besides reading files and regexes in perl